# Xcode circular progress bar with custom start and end point

Tags: ios, progress-bar

Normally, start and end point of circular progress bar are 1 to 100% or 1 to 100. But what I want to try is 1 to 108 or 1 to 9 etc. Please let me know how can I customise it?

Currently, I'm using KAProgressLabel project to embed my app.

[KAProgressLabel](https://github.com/kirualex/KAProgressLabel)

Comment: Have you tried using any maths? What was it? Show it. What did it do wrong?

Comment: hmmm? start/108 to end/108 or start/9 to end/9?

Comment: I have already tried with => (start % 108) * 0.01 like that. But that circular always end to 100 not 108.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 to 108.

start/108.0 to end/108.0

you can try this:

```
_myProgressLabel.labelVCBlock = ^(KAProgressLabel * label) {
    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", label.progress * 107 + 1]];
};
```

Comment: (label.progress*100) * 107 + 1] << it's over 108;

Comment: @ppshein sorry...I fix it. (label.progress * 107 + 1)